# How can I set password strength for IBM Cloud App ID?

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I am using the IBM Cloud App ID service and its Cloud Directory to manage users for my web app. I have a form where users can sign up for the app by providing an username and a password. By default, App ID requires 8 characters minimum for a valid password. How can I change it and adapt it to "my" rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[App ID allows you to set your own password strength policy](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/cloud-directory.html#strength) through the [management APIs](https://appid-management.ng.bluemix.net/swagger-ui/#!/Config/set_cloud_directory_password_regex).
You can supply App ID with a regex, that any new passwords will be validated against. 
This way you can enforce any rules you require.

You can set it using this API: https://appid-management.ng.bluemix.net/swagger-ui/#!/Config/set_cloud_directory_password_regex

A typical policy pattern in JSON format could be:

```
{
  "regex": "^.{8,}$",
  "error_message": "The password must contain at least 8 characters"
}
```